# How to get words from a text box

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application I have a text box named: textBox.
I'm trying to get each individual word from a sentence typed by user in a string array, say arrayWords.
I found a piece of code on stackOverFlow that counts the number of words but I want to copy each individual word.

Bellow is the code for counting the number of words.

```
String text = textBox.Text.Trim();
int wordCount = 0, index = 0;

while (index < text.Length)
{
     // check if current char is part of a word
     while (index < text.Length && Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]) == false)
        index++;
     wordCount++;

    // skip whitespace until next word
    while (index < text.Length && Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]) == true)
        index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Split()` can chop your sentence(s) into words. You should however take care of trimming punctuation characters from your words. For example if you use `Split()` on the sentence "StackOverflow is good, I like it.", two of the words you get in your array will have comma and period characters appended to them. So you should use something like this to get "pure" words:

```
string[] words = textBox.Text.Split().Select(x => x.TrimEnd(",.;:-".ToCharArray())).ToArray();
```

LINQ has been used in the above statement, so you should import `System.Linq`.

Comment: This worked like a charm.
You might want to remove any new lines to textBox.Text and then replace any new lines to make it a little more accurate.  
textBox.Text .replace(Environment.NewLine , "").Split().Select(x => x.TrimEnd(",.;:-".ToCharArray())).ToArray();

It compared with Microsoft Word count to word(s).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

```
String text = textBox.Text.Trim()
var words = text.Split(' ');
```

or

```
 var words = text.Split(); // Default parameter is taken as whitespace delimiter
```

Answer (score 2):

While @dotNET answer is on the right way, it assumes, that you should maintain punctuation marks list yourself (it isn't full in his answer). Besides, there could be words with hyphen.

I'd recommend to use regular expression:

```
var words = Regex.Matches(textBox.Text, @"\w+-?\w+")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give an array of words from your textBox.

```
string[] words = textBox.Text.Split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] words = textBox.Text.Split(new char(" "));
```

Comment: You don't need char ctor here.

Answer (score 0):

Logic behind the getting words from sentence is that first you split sentence into words and then store these words into an array of string then you can do any thing you want. the code below will surely help you to sort out your problem.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sentence = "Thats the sentence";
        string[] operands = Regex.Split(sentence,@" ");
        foreach(string i in operands)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

It will extract words from the sentence and will store in array and will display them.